# Trouble with "unblessed reference" when using HTML::TokeParser

Tags: html, perl

I've been poking a this and can't get around this "unblessed reference" error.  Here's my simplified code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TokeParser;

my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new( $ARGV[0] );
while (my $t = $p->get_tag('img')) {
    my $src = $t->get_attr('src');
    print "$src\n";
}
```

And here's the error message when I try it:

```
Can't call method "get_attr" on unblessed reference at M:\list_images_in_html.pl line 9.
```

I gather that somehow it's not recognizing $t as a token object with a get_attr method, but I don't understand why.

Comment: It doesn't look like `HTML::TokeParse->get_tag()` returns an object.

Comment: From the perldoc -> "The tag information is returned as an array reference in the same form as for $p->get_token above,..."

Comment: Using `Data::Dumper` on `$t` would have been helpful here, too.

Answer (score 4):

According to the manual ([HTML::TokeParse at MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser)), get_tag() returns an array reference, not an object.

You cannot call get_attr() on a bog standard array ref.

Answer (score 1):

`get_attr` is a convenience method in `HTML::TokeParser::Simple` (a wrapper for `HTML::TokeParser`) but does not exist in `HTML::TokeParser`.

Replace two lines in your code with this:

```
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
my $p = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new( $ARGV[0] );
```

and your script will work.